# <sec:authorize ifAllGranted or ifAnyGranted not working in SPRING SECURTIY

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am working on Spring boot and trying to give access to 3 users. But I cannot get that to work.

If I use `ifAnyGranted="ROLE_ADMIN"`, it works fine.

If I use `ifAllGranted="ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_DATA_ADMIN, ROLE_USER"` it does not work, and neither does `ifAnyGranted="ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_DATA_ADMIN, ROLE_USER"`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<sec:ifAnyGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_DATA_ADMIN, ROLE_USER">
 // do stuff
</sec:ifAnyGranted>
```